# Google Maps with fitBounds don't zoom

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

Following code works ok, except that it not zoom to the given points.

If I take the Latlng direct it works, without convert the address to Latlng.

I need to convert a address to latlng because I get the addresses out of a database.

Anyone an idea what is wrong?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html> 
<html>  
<head>  
   <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>  
   <title>Google Maps Test</title>  
   <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"  
           type="text/javascript"></script>  
</head>  
<body>  
   <div id="map" style="width: 600px; height: 400px;"></div>  

   <script type="text/javascript">  

   var arrAddress = new Array();

   arrAddress[0] = "kelbergen, Amsterdam";
   arrAddress[1] = "Kraailookstraat, Amsterdam";
   arrAddress[2] = "krootstraat, Amsterdam";

   var optionMap = {
          zoom: 16,
          MapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP,
          };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), optionMap);

    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    var latlngbounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    for(var i = 0; i < arrAddress.length; i++) {

        geocoder.geocode( { 'address': arrAddress[i]}, function(results, status) {
              if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                      map: map, 
                      position: results[0].geometry.location
                    });

                    latlngbounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
            }
        });

    }

    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

    </script>  
</body>  
</html>
```

Comment: doesn't go to the markers and zoom. with here the url http://www.promeb.nl/test_google_maps.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's geocoder is asynchronous so the `map.fitbounds(latlngbounds)`  is being called before all of the points have been geocoded.  The simplest way to fix this would be to put the `map.fitbounds(latlngbounds)` right after the extend call.

```
for(var i = 0; i < arrAddress.length; i++) {
     geocoder.geocode( { 'address': arrAddress[i]}, function(results, status) {
          if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {

                var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                  map: map, 
                  position: results[0].geometry.location
                });

                latlngbounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);
                map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);

        }
    });
}
```

**UPDATE:**
Here is a better answer.  In the last example the `map.fitbounds(latlngbounds)` method is called repeatedly, which can possibly create problems when there are lots of markers.  Using the answer in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript) you can create an asynchronous loop to make sure the `map.fitbounds(latlngbounds)` is only called once.

```
//replaced the for loop.
asyncLoop(arrAddress.length, function(loop) {
    geocoder.geocode({                           
        'address': arrAddress[loop.iteration()] //loop counter
    }, function(results, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                map: map,
                position: results[0].geometry.location
            });

            latlngbounds.extend(results[0].geometry.location);    
        }

        //increment the loop counter.
        loop.next();
    });
}, function() {
    //when the loop is complete call fit bounds.
    map.fitBounds(latlngbounds);
});    

function asyncLoop(iterations, func, callback) {
    var index = 0;
    var done = false;
    var loop = {
        next: function() {
            if (done) {
                return;
            }

            if (index < iterations) {
                index++;
                func(loop);

            } else {
                done = true;
                callback();
            }
        },

        iteration: function() {
            return index - 1;
        },

        break: function() {
            done = true;
            callback();
        }
    };
    loop.next();
    return loop;
}
```

example has been updated:
[fiddle of the working code.](http://jsfiddle.net/jFMQ5/2/)

Comment: I updated the answer with an example that does not call `map.fitBounds()` multiple times.