# Google Maps API - multiple info windows and automatic centering

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I've been cobbling together various bits of code from around the internet (including StackOverflow) and I've got a working map (almost) which geocodes postcodes from an array and creates infowindows for each one.

Two problems:

1) my info windows, which should take their text from another array, always use the last array value

2) i can't get the map to center automatically. I'm using a bit of code which has worked in other circumstances, but it doesn't in my code.

The code is fairly self-explanatory:

```
var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  //zoom: 10,
  //center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var postcodes = [
    "EH14 1PR",
    "KY7 4TP",
    "IV6 7UP"   
];

var descriptions = [
    "Slateford",
    "Cortachy",
    "Marybank"
];

var markersArray = [];

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i, address, description;

for(var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
    address = postcodes[i];
    description = descriptions[i];
    geocoder.geocode(
        {
            'address': address,
            'region' : 'uk'
        }, 
        function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });
                markersArray[i] = marker;
                console.log(markersArray[i]);
                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                    return function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(description);
                        infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    }
                })(marker, i));
            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " + status);
                return false;
            }
        }
    );

    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();

    $.each(markersArray, function (index, marker) {
        bounds.extend(marker.position);
    });

    map.fitBounds(bounds);
    console.log(bounds);
}
```

Any thoughts? The issue seems to be with the value of the counter *i* inside the geocode function.

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1) my info windows, which should take their text from another array,
>   always use the last array value
>
> 2) i can't get the map to center automatically. I'm using a bit of
>   code which has worked in other circumstances, but it doesn't in my
>   code.

1) Yes this is a closure issue.  This is how I get around it.

I create an object to store all of the properties I will be using.  In your example I am going to use the `postcode` and the `description`.

```
function location(postalcode, desc){
  this.PostalCode = postalcode;
  this.Description = desc;
}
```

Now do a quick loop to add all the `location` objects to an array.

```
var locations = [];
for(var i = 0; i < postcodes.length; i++) {
     locations.push(new location(postcodes[i], descriptions[i]));
}
```

Extract the geocode functionality into its own function with a parameter to take a `location` object.  Then you can loop through the `location` object array and geocode each individually.  So now both the post code and description are in scope when the request is built and sent.

```
function GeoCode(singleLocation){
     geocoder.geocode(
        {
            'address': singleLocation.PostalCode,
            'region' : 'uk'
        }, 
        function(results, status){
            if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
               var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                    position: results[0].geometry.location,
                    map: map
                });

                //quick and dirty way
                bounds.extend(marker.position);
                map.fitBounds(bounds);                    

                markersArray[i] = marker;
                console.log(markersArray[i]);

                google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
                        infowindow.setContent(singleLocation.Description);
                        infowindow.open(map, this); //this refers to the marker
                });

            } else {
                alert("Geocode was not successful for the following reason: " 
                      + status);
                return false;
            }
        }
    );
}
```

2) As you can see above the quick an dirty way to do this is extend and fit the bounds inside of the callback function for the geocode.  This causes the `fitBounds` function to be called multiple times and isnt really a big deal if you only have a few markers, but will cause problems if you have hundreds or thousands of markers.  In that case the *right-way* to do this is to create an async loop function.  You can see an example of it on one of [my previous answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8565539/google-maps-with-fitbounds-dont-zoom).

Here is a [functioning example of the code based on your example](http://jsfiddle.net/gxAtk/).

Comment: Thanks :) I managed it myself by extracting out the various parts (loop, geocode, attach events) into separate functions, but I've not got enough rep to answer my own Q before 8 hours are up! I'll try your solution for the bounds calculation, because I wasn't able to make that work. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Two problems:
>
> 1) my info windows, which should take their text from another array,
>   always use the last array value
>
> 2) i can't get the map to center automatically. I'm using a bit of
>   code which has worked in other circumstances, but it doesn't in my
>   code.

Answers:

1) This is because most likely you have a [closure](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/events.html#EventClosures) issue here.
2) center will define the center point of your map, but in your code you have commented this
`//center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25`),
removing the comment for this line will center to map to latitude of -33.92 and longitude of 151.25.
Use below:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.92, 151.25),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});
```

Comment: I've tried extracting the different stages to separate functions but I'm not having much luck :(. Also, the centre attribute isn't needed (it's commented out on purpose) with that bit of code because it does the centering automagically