# Google Maps API - Not plotting all markers

Tags: google-maps

I'm trying to plot multiple points on a map based on an array of data containing the info window text and the post code. I'm adding a listener as well so that when the marker is clicked the info window pops up.

When I run the following code only the last marker is getting placed. Is anyone able to help on this?

```
<div class="GoogleMap">
  <script src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"type="text/javascript"></script>

  <div id="map" style="width: 977px; height: 600px;"></div>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var locations = [
      ['<h4>Test</h4>', 'CH45 4SQ'],
      ['<h4>Test2</h4>', 'CH63 9AL']
    ];

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      zoom: 8,
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(53.45631, -2.73710),
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ map: map });
    var i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {

      geocoderRequest = {address: locations[i][1]}
      geocoder.geocode(geocoderRequest, function(results, status) {
        marker.setPosition(results[0].geometry.location);
      });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
        return function() {
          infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
          infowindow.open(map, marker);
        }
      })(marker, i));
    }
  </script>

</div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps API - multiple info windows and automatic centering](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8727270/google-maps-api-multiple-info-windows-and-automatic-centering)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are only creating a single marker object and moving it around the map.

Take a look at this example: [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Specifically this part of the code.

```
 var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
```