# Displaying the iterations of a while loop continuously in a text box in Javascript

Tags: javascript, while-loop

Hi I'm trying to display the iterations of a while loop continuously in a text box. However, the browser waits till the loop finishes then displays the final iteration only.
 I'm using this loop to run a complex function which means the iterations will be slower and can be seen if displayed in the console:

For example, I'm trying to do something like this.
in HTML:

```
    <p>
      <label>This is generation number</label>
      <input type = "number"
             id = "generation"
             />
    </p>
```

in Javascript:

```
function Run(){

var i=0;

while (i<500) { 

document.getElementById('generation').value= i;

i++
        }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Javascript async loop processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9772400/javascript-async-loop-processing)

Comment: You cannot do this with a synchronous `while` loop. Use a recursive approach and `requestAnimationFrame` instead. Of course, this will be more complicated in your real code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not do it synchronously (No `while` loop). This locks up the browser and does not allow anything else to happen. No draw cycle can happen and it looks like nothing it changing.

Try breaking it into a function that only does one step and then call it over and over through a timeout.

```js
    var updateEl = document.getElementById("generation");
    var i;

    function doStep() {
      //super crazy code
      updateEl.value = i;
      i++;
      if (i < 500) {
        timeout = setTimeout(doStep);
      }
    }


    function Run() {
      i = 0;
      doStep();
    }
```

> If you need this process to be as fast as possible you want `setTimeout`. If you want to synchronize with the animation buffer of canvas or speed is not a real issue then use [requestAnimationFrame](http://devdocs.io/dom/window/requestanimationframe).

**UPDATE**

To match what @Brian is saying in his comment below:

```js
var updateEl = document.getElementById("generation");

function doStep(i) {
  //super crazy code
  updateEl.value = i++;
  if (i < 500) {
    timeout = setTimeout(() => doStep(i));
  }
}


function Run() {
  doStep(0);
}
```

```html
<p>
  <label>This is generation number</label>
  <input type="number" id="generation"/>
</p> 
<button onclick="Run()">Run</button>
```

Comment: You can pass `i` to the function - no more side effects!