# Save string from jQuery's `$.get`

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'd like to load some content from an URL, to use it in my code. I tried closures and this:

```
function getStringFromURL(url) {
  var getter = function() {
    this.result = "undef";
    this.func = function(response) {
      this.result = response;
    };
  };
  var x = new getter();
  $.get(url, x.func);
  return x.result;  // the it returns "undef" and not the wanted response
}
```

Nothing worked at all. I'll never got the content, but if I call it with `alert` like `$.get("http://localhost:9000/x", function(response) { 
    alert(response) 
});` it works -- but I'd like to save the response. I think theres a problem with the scope of the `$.get`-method.

Whats wrong with this?

Answer (score 3):

You can't analyze the content obtained from another domain or port in a standard get query without an explicit accord given by the server.

Read this : https://developer.mozilla.org/en/http_access_control
You'll see how to define the proper header for your site so that it says the browser that cross-domain requests are fine.

And you have a closure problem. Try this if you want to call x.func in another context than the getter :

```
var getter = function() {
   var _this = this;
   this.result = "undef";
   this.func = function(response) {
      _this.result = response;
     };
 };
```

EDIT : And as other have mentionned, you cannot return immediately x.result from `getStringFromURL`. You must use the value in the callback. In fact, it's more generally not possible to define a synchronous getter in javascript around an asynchronous call.

Comment: Why works the code with `alert`? (`$.get("http://localhost:9000/x", function(response) { alert(response) });`)

Comment: Because you're probably testing the website locally on your computer. So it's the same origin and you're allowed to process your own data.

Comment: Some things are possible. Like alert, fill a div for display, console.log. Some aren't.

Comment: Sadly it's no closure-problem, "undef" is returned anyway -- and despite of the changes with the code-snippets from Beygi.

Comment: The function returns before the asynchronous call calls the callback is neither a closure nor a cross domain issue (which would also fail in the alert version)

Comment: @RuneFS : The x.func function is passed as a callback to the $.get function. So there is no asynchronicity problem.

Comment: Sure there is since he's using the value set by the call back before the call back is called. Which is why the value is still the original value

Comment: Ah, you mean in the last line. Yes, I missed that and you're perfectly right.

Answer (score 1):

$.get is Async method

you need to pass a callback function as an argument to getStringFromURL

```
function getStringFromURL(url, callback) {
            var getter = function () {
                this.result = "undef";
                this.func = function (response) {
                    this.result = response;
                    callback(response);
                };
            };
            var x = new getter();
            $.get(url, x.func);
        }

getStringFromURL("http://localhost:9000/x", function (res) { alert(res) });
```

if you want to return the result it is impossible.

> You can't mix synchronous and asynchronous in JavaScript if you block
>   the script, you block the Browser.

check it out here [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript)

Comment: This won't change the problems with the same origin policy.

Comment: @chucktato there is no problem with origin policy here http://localhost:9000/ is his website and /x is the URL he wants to load as he mentioned in his question, he didn't say i want to load some content from a domain and i have a problem because when i load localhost it works.

Comment: The `alert` prompts the correct answer from localhost, but "undef" is returned anyway.

Comment: You shouldn't return but pass the value to the continuation (callback)

Comment: The question says: "I'd like to load some content from an URL". He stated that localhost works, but any other URL doesn't. The problem with the callback function is additional, as he gets the wrong output if he inserts an `alert()` too.