# Loop through js array continually with pauses

Tags: javascript, jquery, foreach

I want to loop over an array continuously on click. Extra props if you can work in a delay between class switches :-)

I got this far:

```
// Define word
var text = "textthing";

// Define canvas
var canvas = 'section';

// Split word into parts
text.split();

// Loop over text
$(canvas).click(function() {

    $.each(text, function(key, val) {
        $(canvas).removeAttr('class').addClass(val);
    });

});
```

Which is not too far at all :-)

Any tips?

Comment: Er.. what again? Your question still doesn't say why you want to do this..

Comment: This logic is flawed: `var text = 'lorem'; text.split(); console.log(text) // lorem`. Do this instead: `var text = 'lorem'.split(''); console.log(text) // [l, o, r, e, m]`

Comment: @elclanrs. Yes, that's more succinct but I wish to populate that text var via a input element later down the line, and this makes it clearer.

Comment: What I mean is that `text.split()` won't update the variable unless you assign it again. ie. `text = text.split()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following will wait until you click the selected element(s) in the var `el`. In this example `var el = $('section')` will select all `<section>...</section>` elements in your document.

Then it will start cycling through the values in `cssClassNames`, using each, in turn as the css class name on the selected element(s).  A delay of `delayInMillis` will be used between each class change.

```
var cssClassNames = ['c1', 'c2', 'c3'];
var el = $('section');
var delayInMillis = 1000;

// Loop over text
el.click(function() {
  var i = 0;
  function f() {
    if( i >= cssClassNames.length ) {
      i = 0;
    }
    var currentClass = cssClassNames[i];
    i += 1;

    el.removeClass().addClass(currentClass);
    setTimeout(f, delayInMillis);
  }
  f();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want a delay of X milliseconds between removing a class and adding a class.  I'm not sure that you have to have the lines marked // ? or even that they do the job, but what you do have to have is a way to get the value's into the function.  Also, the setTimeout anon function might not actually need the parameters, but it should give you an idea.

```
$(canvas).click(function() {

    $.each(text, function(key, val) {
        $(canvas).removeAttr('class')
        var $canvas = $(canvas) //?
        var class_val = val  //?
        setTimeout(function ($canvas, class_val) {
            $canvas.addClass(class_val);
        }, 2000);

   });

});
```

Edit:  I'd do this instead
    function modify_element($element, class_name){
        $element.removeClass('class');
        setTimeout(function ($element) {
            $element.addClass(class_name);
        }, 1000);
        //adds the class 1 second after removing it
    }

```
$(canvas).click(function() {

    $.each(text, function(key, val) {
        setTimeout(modify_element($(canvas), val),2000);
        //this will loop over the elements with 2 seconds between elements
    });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

"loop over an array continuously" this sounds like a infinite loop, I don't think you want that. About pausing the loop, this is possible, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript/11195609#11195609)