# Chaining $.Deferred

Tags: jquery, jquery-deferred

I'm hoping to understand why I'm getting different behavior when attemping to chain a deferred object directly than I do when attempting to chain by saving the object in a variable and invoking one or more deferred methods on that variable.

When saving the object in a variable, the value sent in to each function is the same (in the case of the code snippet below, 5) - i.e. the values don't filter in this case.  When chained directly, the values filter...  so I'm unclear on how get filtering to occur when setting up a `Deferred.pipe()` in several different statements.  And by my reading of the [jquery docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), it should be possible:

> The Deferred object is chainable, similar to the way a jQuery object is chainable, but it has its own methods. After creating a Deferred object, you can use any of the methods below by either chaining directly from the object creation or saving the object in a variable and invoking one or more methods on that variable.

What am I doing wrong?

Here is my code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
// This works as expected - alert(20)

var defer = new $.Deferred();
defer.pipe(myFunction).pipe(myFunction).pipe(myAlert);
defer.resolve(5);

// This does not work as expected - alert(5)
var defer2 = new $.Deferred();
defer2.pipe(myFunction);
defer2.pipe(myFunction);
defer2.pipe(myAlert);
defer2.resolve(5);

});

var myFunction = function (value) {
return value * 2;
}

var myAlert = function (value) {
alert('The value is ' + value);
}
</script>
```

Comment: It's likely that some operations return a new promise (like `.pipe()`) so chaining would operate on the newly returned object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `$.Deferred` object is indeed chainable, but in your second scenario, you are not chaining anything; you are just assigning multiple `pipe`s to the `$.Deferred` object to be executed independently, when the `$.Deferred` is either resolved or rejected. In other words, you are **ignoring** the returned `Promise` object which *contains* the filtered/modified value to be passed to the next `.pipe()` in the chain.

From the [docs](http://api.jquery.com/deferred.pipe/):

> The deferred.pipe() method **returns a new promise that filters** the
>   status and values of a deferred through a function.

To achieve what you want in your second example, `pipe` the resulting `Promise` instead of the original `$.Deferred` object:

```
var defer2 = new $.Deferred();
var promise = defer2.pipe(myFunction);
promise = promise.pipe(myFunction); // pipe and update promise
promise.pipe(myAlert);
defer2.resolve(5);
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/kU9nz/)**.

Comment: Thank you.  So in the case of pipe(), it's literal. :) I accept that, even though it's inconsistent with the documentation I cited above.  Here's the challenge - I don't know how many pipe() calls I'll need to make, so I'm wondering if there is a clean way to chain a variable number of functions together and still get the filtering behavior (using pipe() or otherwise).

Comment: @AndrewH: Yes, there is, store each intermediate `Promise` object, and keep piping it. Here's an example: http://jsfiddle.net/kU9nz/. It's the exact same idea as yours, but by piping through the returned `Promise` object.

Answer (score -1):

Joao, I had the same case - unknown number of pipe to be called.
here is how do that - [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript/12637748#12637748)