# While loop is not working properly in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use while loop in Angular.
If I use `alert` in while loop, it give same quantity output. but I remove `alert`, the quantity is different. So what is wrong in my code.

```
var quantity= $scope.quantity;
var i=0;
while(i< quantity)
        {
                        order.createOrderLineItem( localStorage.getItem( "orderID" ), itemStr, undefined, $scope.errorCallback )
                .success(function(data){
                $scope.lineItemID = data.id;

                alert("i:"+i);
                var orderLineItemData = {};
                if( $scope.cusNote == "" )
                {
                    var existedNote = data.note || "";
                    orderLineItemData = {
                        "unitQty": $scope.quantity,
                        "note": existedNote,
                    };

                    //if adding taxRates 0, clover will returns error
                    if($scope.taxRates !== 0) {
                        orderLineItemData.taxRates = $scope.taxRates;
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    var customerNote = "";

                    if( data.note != undefined && data.note != null ) customerNote = data.note;

                    customerNote = customerNote + "#order-request-[";
                    customerNote = customerNote + $scope.cusNote;
                    customerNote = customerNote + "]";
                    customerNote = customerNote.replace(/\\/g, '\\\\');
                    customerNote = customerNote.replace(/\"/g, '\\"');

                    console.log( "customerNote:" + customerNote );

                    orderLineItemData = {
                        "unitQty":$scope.quantity,
                        "note": customerNote,
                        "taxRates": $scope.taxRates
                    }
                }

                order.updateOrderLineItem( localStorage.getItem( "orderID" ), $scope.lineItemID, JSON.stringify(orderLineItemData), undefined, $scope.errorCallback )
                    .success( function( data ){
                        if( $scope.modCount == 0 )
                        {
                            location.href = "/" + $routeParams.slug;
                        }

                        $scope.addModifierItem( $scope.lineItemID );
                    });
            });
            i++;
        }
```

So how can I correct this code?

Comment: Seems lik eyou are using async calls within a sync loop... the results are unexpected.

Comment: So, how can i make change in it

Comment: It is not clear from the code example, but it appears as if you want to run all the requests in serial and not in parallel. Is that the case?

Comment: User promisses i guess. there is something called async.each but its for nodejs only i think

Comment: there is a suggestion here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function? - Asynchronous code reference](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron)

Comment: Marked this as a duplicate of [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Calling `alert()` blocks the current execution, so it gives the asynchronous code time to complete.

Answer (score 0):

**I am not sure but**, alert may be the reason of that. Can you try to use `console.log("i:"+i);` instead of the alert. Browser may interrupt when you use alert because of the pop up.

--Edited--

this is the service that you will need to implement into your application. You will need to notify this service at your success and it will trigger any observe that is implemented after the notify

```
 app.service('checkService',['$q',function($q){
        var checkRequest = $q.defer();

        this.notifyRequestIsDone= function(){
            checkRequest .notify();
        };

        this.observeRequestStatus = function(){
            return checkRequest .promise;
        };
    }]);
```

Here is observe example of the code above add this to your controller where you need to increase your value after the request is done

```
checkService.observeRequestStatus ().then(null,null,function(){
    //... Your code
});
```

Comment: I see that you are requesting a data and doing some work on the success. You should notice that if you are calling a http request there will be a delay on return from server. so if there is no alert the javascript will not wait for the return an increment the "i" but if you add alert it will stop the js until you hit the button on the pop up so this makes a time gap for the request return. You can broadcast or use a defer to get the success properly. I hope this would help you

Comment: how to use defer in that