# Access correct value of a variable in asynchronous behavior

Tags: javascript, node.js

In the following code, last line logs value of output as empty since it is executed before queries are completed.How to resolve this problem using async library of node.js?

```
var output;
for (var j = 0; j < someArr.length; j++) {
    tVal = someArr[j]; //some manipulation of someArr[i]
    (function (val) {
        connection.query("select id from someTable where someCol = ?", val, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err);
            } else {
                output.push(rows[0].someVal); //push query output to this variable
            }
        });
    })(tVal);
}
console.log(output); // outputs empty array sincebefore queries are completed.
```

Comment: Use `async` of `bluebird` package

Comment: I think we can use both async/promises to achieve this task but i can not get my head around as to how to do it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

There are too many approaches to solve your problem.

No doubt the best one is using promises (but you should learn a bit about them before). There are a lot or resources in the net explaining it. Some better and some poorer.

There is a really good and extense explanation about that in the [Async and Performance](https://github.com/getify/You-Dont-Know-JS/tree/master/async%20%26%20performance) book. But, sure, you could find shorter howto's in the net.

On the other hand, if you are only searching for a fast and simple (but not as escalable and elegant) solution, can simply check for the fullfillment (Oh! this is a promise concept!) of the array in the query handler clalback:

```
if (j == somArr.lengt - 1) {
    console.log(output)
};
```

...Or a little bit less dirty approach: Unconditionally call some predefined function like:

```
function checkLast() {
    if (output.length >= someArr.length) {
        console.log(output);
    };
};
```

**Edit:** If you would try, using promise should look like this (untested). But it could depend on the exact implementation library:

```
var tasks;

for (var j = 0; j < someArr.length; j++) {
    tVal = someArr[j]; //some manipulation of someArr[i]
    tasks.push(new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        connection.query("select id from someTable where someCol = ?", val, function (err, rows, fields) {
            if (err) { 
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(rows[0].someVal);
            }   
        }); 
    }));        
}           

Promise.all(tasks)
.then(function(data) {
    console.log(data);
})
.catch(function(err){
    console.log(err);
});
```