# Javascript function with async callback doesn't change dom inside loop

Tags: javascript, function, dom

I have a function which needs to be run 197 times.I used a simple for loop to iterate it.

```
for(var m=0;m<198;++m) {
     console.log($('#riddle').attr('index')+" "+$('#riddle').attr('word'));
     submitN();     
}
```

For each iteration this should print the Index and Word attribute of Id=riddle and then execute the submitN function which changes the Index and Word attribute.

However The function executes only once.

This is what I get-
 [image]

If I execute the submitN seperately function without loop for 197 times , it works fine

[image]

Pressing the key 197 times is a very inefficient, I would like some help to make it run with the loop.

EDIT

submitN function

```
function submitN() {
    var i_val = $('#riddle').attr('next');
    req_n = sendData(JSON.stringify({'i':i_val}),'/clue');
    req_n.done(munchClues);
    req_n.fail(clueFail);
}
```

Comment: Look at your first screenshot. See the blue "198" next to "0 right"? That's the console saying "this thing was printed 198 times in a row, but I didn't want to bother you with all of them".

Comment: And not showing submitN() is due to???

Comment: the function works 198 time :)

Comment: Most  likely your `submitN` does some async code. As already noted the `198` beside the log entry shows you that it printed `198` times.

Comment: But it's  value should change  each time , as showed in the 2nd screenshot.

Comment: Then we'd need to see `submitN()`. Currently the question is "why doesn't this loop execute more than once", but it does.

Comment: And `sendData` Is it a async api call? If so you loop is continuing regardless.

Comment: Because you use `done` and `fail` indicates that you use the Promise functionality of jQuery (e.g. of `$.getJSON`, `$.ajax`, `$.get`, ...), or something similar. And I assume that in `munchClues` the `$('#riddle')` will be changed. The problem with that is that this will be done async, so every `munchClues`  call will happen  **after**  the main loop finished.

Comment: Yes it is Async, it uses ajax.Is there a way to try what I am doing in Async api call.

Comment: Async means that it executes "in its own time," in this case separate from and ultimately after the loop. The values will not have had a chance to change between each `console.log()`. Whereas running the command directly in the console affords it that chance. If you want each iteration to "*wait*" until the previous has completed, you'll have to find a alternate iterator to the `for` loop: [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript)

Comment: Thanks @JonathanLonowski

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To wait for the async call each time like @ste2425 and @t.niese said, you can wait to check the dom inside the sendData callback:

```
var m = 0;
function checkRiddle(){
  m++;
  console.log($('#riddle').attr('index')+" "+$('#riddle').attr('word'));
  submitN();  
}
checkRiddle();

function submitN() {
  var i_val = $('#riddle').attr('next');
  req_n = sendData(JSON.stringify({'i':i_val}),'/clue');
  req_n.done(function(params){
    munchClues(params);
    if(m<198){
      checkRiddle();
    }
  }); 
  req_n.fail(clueFail);
}
```

This assumes that munchClues is only using one param. Some testing may be required to successfully inject this code inside the done callback.

Comment: Did the trick ! Thanks