# How does node event loop decide when to switch flows?

Tags: node.js

I use nodejs on a Rasbperry pi to control its hardware pins.
I was completely assuming that code such as:

```
for (..) {
  executeAsyncCode(..)
}

function executeAsyncCode() {
 doAsync1().then(doAsync2()).then(doAsync3())...
}
```

will eventually be executed in such manner that each execution of `executeAsyncCode` will be completely separated from others, meaning that two asynchronous executions wont be running at the same time. But real-time verification and usage shows differently. I encounter executions where `doAsync1(..)` is called one after the other for two executions of `executeAsyncCode` function, and doing a lot of mess during that.

To my usage its obviously a problem, as hardware cant be used in parallel, and there are many cases where I might want to execute code and rely on the fact that no locks are required.
How can such code be limited to not execute all together? Is there a way of knowing how the event loop will execute code?

Comment: Related: [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript) If you want to run one iteration at a time, you'll need an iterator that is aware of asynchronous operations.

Comment: FYI, this `doAsync1().then(doAsync2()).then(doAsync3())...` should be this: `doAsync1().then(doAsync2).then(doAsync3);`.

Answer (score 1):

All code will finish executing before the event loop will start the next context. That means that a loop will always execute to completion before any async callbacks are executed. For example:

```
for ( var i = 0; i < 100000; i++ ) {
    console.log( 'Hi!' );
    setTimeout( function ( ) { console.log( 'foo' ); }, 0 );
}

// Some synchronous operation that takes a long time 

console.log( 'bar' );
```

Will deterministically output 'Hi!' 100000 times followed by `'bar'` and then since there is nothing more in the script the event loop gets a chance for the other messages to run and finally `'foo'` is output 100000 times.

If you want to wait for the first promise chain to finish before starting the next one, you should return a Promise from `executeAsyncCode` so that you can start the next one when it completes:

```
var previousPromise = Promise.resolve();
for (..) {
  previousPromise = previousPromise.then( executeAsyncCode );
}

function executeAsyncCode() {
  return doAsync1().then(doAsync2).then(doAsync3)...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To wait for all your async code to finish before running them again you have to execute the next round inside the `.then()`. Since you are already using promises you only need to return the chain:

```
function executeAsyncCode() {
  return doAsync1().then(doAsync2).then(doAsync3)...
}
```

Then `executeAsyncCode()` can itself continue on a `.then()`:

```
executeAsyncCode()
.then(function(){
    console.log('finished');
});
```

So, two loops would be:

```
executeAsyncCode()
.then(executeAsyncCode);
```

Five loops would be:

```
executeAsyncCode()
.then(executeAsyncCode)
.then(executeAsyncCode)
.then(executeAsyncCode)
.then(executeAsyncCode)
.then(executeAsyncCode);
```

To do an infinite loop, you can use the old setTimeout-style loop trick used by javascript animators and game programmers. This is an infinite loop:

```
function executeAsyncCode() {
  doAsync1()
  .then(doAsync2)
  .then(doAsync3)
  .then(executeAsyncCode);
}
```

Alternatively:

```
function executeAsyncCode() {
  doAsync1()
  .then(doAsync2)
  .then(doAsync3)
  .then(function(){
    executeAsyncCode();
  });
}
```

This second syntax allows us to write conditional loops:

```
function executeAsyncCode() {
  doAsync1()
  .then(doAsync2)
  .then(doAsync3)
  .then(function(){
    if (we_should_loop()) {
      executeAsyncCode();
    }
  });
}
```

We can also structure our code so that we can pass the loop condition as an argument. This is a simple countdown loop:

```
function executeAsyncCode(count) {
  doAsync1()
  .then(doAsync2)
  .then(doAsync3)
  .then(function(){
    count--;
    if (count) {
      executeAsyncCode(count);
    }
  });
}
```

So we can call it like this:

```
executeAsyncCode(5); // runs 5 loops
```

This emulates a simple for loop:

```
function executeAsyncCode(start, end) {
  doAsync1()
  .then(doAsync2)
  .then(doAsync3)
  .then(function(){
    start--;
    if (start < end) {
      executeAsyncCode(start,end);
    }
  });
}

executeAsyncCode(0, 20); // loops 20 times
```

This tries to emulate most of the features of a for loop:

```
function executeAsyncCode(x, checkfunction, incrementfunction) {
  if (checkfunction(x)) {
    doAsync1()
    .then(doAsync2)
    .then(doAsync3)
    .then(function(){
      executeAsyncCode(incrementfunction(x));
    });
  }
}
```

So you can sort of call it like a for loop:

```
// loops 10 times like a for loop:
executeAsyncCode(0, function(i){return i<10}, function(i){return i++});
```

Comment: Note that while the code above looks like recursion they're not recursion. What they do instead is schedule tasks to execute at a later time. So there is no risk of the stack growing infinitely for the infinite loops.