# Running multiple command lines in series

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am trying to run a command line, after a command line. The purpose is to go into the correct directory and then create a folder there.

I have looked at the node.js api, although the code looks complicated and it doesnt directly show how to run multiple command line arguments.

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');
exec(['cd desktop', 'mkdir Folder'], (err) => {
    if (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }
});
```

I am hoping to go into the "desktop" directory, and then create a folder there. The whole purpose is to run the following two commands in series.

```
cd desktop
mkdir Folder
```

Answer (score 1):

According to [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback), `child_process.exec()` takes a string command argument, not an array of commands.

To chain two commands, like in your example, you can do:

```
const { exec } = require('child_process');

exec('cd desktop && mkdir Folder', (err) => {
  if (err) console.log(err);
});
```

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36959253/how-can-i-execute-shell-commands-in-sequence) if you want to chain more commands sequentially.