# Mongoose .create( ) not saving entries to db

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My seed file is supposed to seed 2 users into my MongoDB. My **db.User.remove( )** is definitely deleting any existing users in my db, so I am accessing the right db. However, **newUser.save( )** isn't actually saving records.

My console.log is showing that my 2 user objects from user_list have been generated, but my newUser.save( ) is not actually saving new records to the User collection (it's completely empty). Any ideas?

**seed.js**

```
// remove all users
db.User.remove({}, function(err, users){
    if(err) {
    console.log('Error occurred in remove', err);
    } else {
        console.log('removed all users');
        // create new records based on the array user_list
        for (i=0; i < user_list.length; i++) {
            var newUser = new User();
            // set the user's local credentials
            newUser.email = user_list[i].email;
            newUser.password = createHash(user_list[i].password);
            newUser.company = user_list[i].company;
            newUser.firstName = user_list[i].firstName;
            newUser.lastName = user_list[i].lastName;
            newUser.admin = user_list[i].admin;
            console.log(newUser);
            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err, users) {
                if (err){
                    console.log('Error in Saving user: '+ err);  
                    throw err; 
                } 
            });
        }
        console.log("created", user_list.length, "users");
        process.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Note: [Asynchronous for cycle in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4288759/asynchronous-for-cycle-in-javascript)

Comment: Nice! Great context. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`save` operation is asynchronous(non-blocking) and as a result, `process.exit();` will be executed earlier then save operation. `user_list` seems to an array with static data. Try to log `users` variable or just any  marker in `save` callback instead.

The way to fix it is to aggregate and use promises or place check for the last user in `save` callback.

Comment: Actually, found a solution. This put me on the right track. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As Konstantin mentioned, process.exit( ) was getting called before save. There are better solutions, but simple answer was to delay the process.exit( ) by adding a counter:

```
// remove all users
db.User.remove({}, function(err, users){
    if(err) {
    console.log('Error occurred in remove', err);
    } else {
        console.log('removed all users');
        // create new records based on the array user_list
        var count = 1;
        for (i=0; i < user_list.length; i++) {
            var newUser = new User();
            // set the user's local credentials
            newUser.email = user_list[i].email;
            newUser.password = createHash(user_list[i].password);
            newUser.company = user_list[i].company;
            newUser.firstName = user_list[i].firstName;
            newUser.lastName = user_list[i].lastName;
            newUser.admin = user_list[i].admin;
            console.log(newUser);
            // save the user
            newUser.save(function(err, users) {
                count += 1;
                if (err){
                    console.log('Error in Saving user: '+ err);  
                    throw err; 
                } else if (count == user_list.length) {
                    process.exit();
                }
            });
        }
        console.log("created", user_list.length, "users");
    }
});
```

Comment: Have you tried running code without `process.exit()`? Because current code doesn't delay anyhow, it just performs a check and if it fails, skips `process.exit()`.

Comment: Yes, it freezes without an exit. I think, because the count iteration isn't happening until the save callback (save has already run), then process.exit( ) is ignored until after 2 saves (or as many saves as my user_list is long). Do you know of a cleaner solution?

Comment: Yeah, as I mentioned in an answer, you should move check that you've just created inside `save` callback.